# Che cos'è un "negozio di colori"?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto queste parole pronunciate dal padre dell'autore:

> «Ero commesso in un **negozio di colori** in via Calzaiuoli. La mamma faceva la sarta in un laboratorio del Corso, lì vicino».

Potreste spiegarmi cos'è un "negozio di colori"? Una ricerca su Google di questa espressione mi ha condotto a siti web che parlano di diversi tipi di negozi: di pitture per muri, di articoli di belle arti, di regali...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La voce del Dizionario biografico Treccani (http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/vasco-pratolini_%28Dizionario-Biografico%29/) dedicata a Pratolini ci aiuta a rispondere: «Il padre, Ugo, era commesso nel negozio di colori e articoli da disegno Zolfanelli & Neri di via de’ Calzaioli».

Si tratta, dunque, di un negozio di “belle arti”, vale a dire un negozio dove si poteva comprare tutto il necessario per disegnare e dipingere (matite, pennelli, modellini, colori a olio, a tempera, e così via). Di solito erano vicino alle Accademie di belle arti. Ancora oggi ne restano alcuni ad esempio a Roma, nella zona di Fontanella Borghese, o a Milano, nei dintorni dell’Accademia di Brera, e naturalmente a Firenze.

Comment: si chiama anche colorificio

Comment: In *questo caso* sappiamo che il negozio vendeva articoli di belle arti. Ma "negozio di colori", genericamente, indica un negozio dove si trovano colori, senza specificare la loro destinazione: può vendere pitture murali e tappezzerie ma non acquerelli, oppure può vendere acquerelli e carboncini ma non pitture murali e pennellesse.

Answer (score 2):

Un negozio di colori vende in genere tutti i generi di pitture e vernici per vari usi: edilizia, belle arti, pittura del legno, ecc.

Puoi quindi trovarci pittura per decorare le pareti, colori per dipingere quadri e disegnare ed inoltre pittura per legno.

Al giorno d’oggi l’offerta si è evoluta e si può ottenere la colorazione desiderata sul momento ed inoltre si trovano vernici e pitture per qualsiasi scopo.